# Knockout - setting the initial value of a select

Tags: knockout.js

The span for the selected value in my code doesn't seem to populate initially. Can anyone tell me why this is?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vVLdQ/

My HTML:

```
<div>
Disable:
 <span data-bind="text: options[1].text"></span><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: options[1].disable" />
 <span data-bind="text: options[2].text"></span><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: options[2].disable" />
 <span data-bind="text: options[3].text"></span><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: options[3].disable" />
</div>
<div>
<select data-bind="value: selectedValue">
 <option data-bind="value: options[0].text, text: options[0].text"></option>
 <option data-bind="value: options[1].text, text: options[1].text, disable: options[1].disable"></option>
 <option data-bind="value: options[2].text, text: options[2].text, disable: options[2].disable"></option>
 <option data-bind="value: options[3].text, text: options[3].text, disable: options[3].disable"></option>
</select>
</div>
<span data-bind="text: selectedValue"></span>
```

My Javascript:

```
var selectModel;

function OptionModel(text) {
    var me = this;
    me.text = text;
    me.disable = ko.observable(false);
    me.disable.subscribe(function(disableVal) {
        if (disableVal && selectModel.selectedValue() == me.text) {
            selectModel.selectedValue('-- Select --');
        }
    });
}
var options = [
    new OptionModel('-- Select --'),
    new OptionModel('a'),
    new OptionModel('b'),
    new OptionModel('c')
    ];
selectModel = {
    options: options,
    selectedValue: ko.observable(options[0].text)
};
ko.applyBindings(selectModel);​
```

Comment: Why not using the [options](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html) binding to populate the _select_ ?

Comment: If you can show me a way to disable options via binding, I'd be glad to!

Comment: Indeed... I don't see a way using options. Here is another solution using _foreach_ instead: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gbos/vVLdQ/5/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**: as nemesv said in the comments: "The `select data-bind="value: selectedValue"` binding runs when there is no option value populated yet which resets the `selectedValue` to `null`."

From another StackOverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972367/knockoutjs-select-with-option-group), I came up with this:

```
<select data-bind="foreach: options, value: selectedValue">
    <option data-bind="text: text, value: text, disable: disable"></option>
</select>
```

I also changed some things around in the check boxes as well to make it more readable. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rynan/s5qSE/) for full example.

Comment: It is the order of the databinding execution which causes the original problem. The `select data-bind="value: selectedValue"` bindings runs when there is no option value populated yet which resets the `selectedValue` to `null`. Your solution nicely solves this problem.

Comment: Thanks, I thought it might be that but wasn't entirely certain. I'll edit my answer so that that information will be easily visible to everyone.