# optgroup with foreach to be converted to li and ul

Tags: knockout.js

```
I have knock out section Below

<select>

   <option value="0|-1">All</option>
   <optgroup data-bind="repeat: { foreach : ViewModel.availableLists, bind : 'attr: { label :     $item().ProjectName }, foreach : $item().Lists' }">
     <option data-bind="text : ListName" />
   </optgroup>

</select>
```

But I want to convert this select drop down  to Ul  and Li, i am failing to convert this to ul and li. How can i do that?

Each optgroup  should be rendered as an li with css class "project-name".
Under each project-name Each option  should be rendered as an li with css class "list-name".

Comment: Please edit your question and tell us what you've got so far, be specific about the problem you're experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972367/knockoutjs-select-with-option-group) syntax can help you to create an options groups in your binding

Also note that the `<li>` are automatically created by the `options` binding using the items in your binded model (this is the idea of the binding). You can read the [knockout options binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html) documentation